# Triviality of the Euler totient of a non-cyclic Abelian group

Tags: combinatorics, abelian-groups

Recall that the Euler totient $\phi(n)$ satisfies the identity
$$\phi(n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\mu(d) = n\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}.$$
This computation can be interpreted as computing a certain invariant of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n$ as follows. Given a finite group $G$, let $\mu(G)$ be the Mobius function defined inductively by $\mu(1) = 1$ and for $G\neq 1$
$$\mu(G) = -\sum_{H<G} \mu(H).$$
Then we can define a generalized Euler totient
$$\phi(G) := \sum_{H\leqslant G} [G:H]\mu(H) = |G|\sum_{H\leqslant G}\frac{\mu(H)}{|H|},$$
so that $\phi(\mathbb{Z}/n) = \phi(n)$.

This function came up while I was doing some computations in the incidence algebra of the lattice of subgroups of $G$. I've seen a few papers that consider generalized Euler totients defined on finite groups, but they all seem to consider definitions that are not equivalent to the one given above. Which is actually pretty reasonable, since it turns out the above definition is trivial!

**Proposition.** For any non-cyclic finite Abelian group $G$, $\phi(G) = 0$.

It's not terribly difficult to prove this assertion. By multiplicativity it suffices to consider the case where $G$ is a non-cyclic $p$-group. By standard properties of the Mobius function, $\mu(H) = 0$ unless $H$ is contained in the socle of $G$. So it suffices to show the result for $G = (C_p)^n$ with $n>1$. Using Hall's formula
$$\mu((C_p)^n) = (-1)^n p^{\binom{n}{2}}$$
and basic counting we obtain the formula
$$\phi((C_p)^n) = p^n \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}p^{\binom{k}{2}}p^{-k} \binom{n}{k}_p$$
where $\binom{n}{k}_p$ is the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{F}_p^n$. Then applying the $q$-binomial theorem we can simplify this expression to
$$\phi((C_p)^n) = p^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-p^{k-1})$$
which clearly vanishes if $n>1$ due to the $k=1$ term.

> **Question:** The computational proof outlined above doesn't really explain *why* the proposition is true, but presumably the result should be a reflection of some simple structural property of non-cyclic Abelian groups. Is there a more conceptual proof of this result, or at least some intuition that shows how one might have predicted the result a priori?

Comment: The interpretation $\phi(G)=\phi_1(G)$ as the number of generators of $G$?

Comment: @user10354138 Aha, I see, thank you :-)